# Is it possible to create separate case-insensitive "view" on existing filesystem?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I use on my Linux some badly-written scripts that don't care about case sensitivity in file names. I wonder whether it is possible to create a virtual/proxy/transient case-insensitive file system that points to existing files on ext4 or btrfs but without case sensitivity.
I'd like to have mounted both at the same time.

Comment: http://www.brain-dump.org/projects/ciopfs/

Comment: Good idea, bad reality. It filters-out all names containing upper case.